# NSNull stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: issue with a JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

i've a problem with parsing a JSON:

in mycallback method i copy object for key "a" in a NSDictionary *test  as follow:

```
[[test sharedManager] MyTestCallback:^(MyTestSessionStatus status, NSDictionary * t, NSError * error){


test = [t objectForKey:@"a"];
}
```

then in an other method i copy in an array the value

```
NSArray *temp = [discoveredMedia valueForKeyPath:@"b"];
```

and then when i try to do

```
NSString *temp2 = (NSString *)[temp objectAtIndex:0];
```

but value is -> Printing description of temp2:  < null >

and in debugger ->  temp2   NSString *  class name = NSNull 0x383ed3d0

it crushed when

```
temp2 = (NSString *)[temp2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<$size$" withString:@"350"];
```

in console:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x383ed3d0'

what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: check your string is nil, cant call method stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString

Comment: I've tried but temp2 is not null!! 

 It contains a value -> description is < null >

I ve tried with
 if([temp2 isEqualToString:@""] || [temp isEqualToString:@"<null>"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON you have 'null' in dictionary and it will return in objective c not nil but NSNull.
You need to treat NSNull as nil.

Comment: Yes, how i can check if 

NSArray *temp = [discoveredMedia valueForKeyPath:@"b"]; is a NSNULL value? i've tried with if([temp objectAtIndex:0] == [NSNull null] )
        {temp=nil};
but it still not work

Comment: Try NSArray *temp = discoveredMedia[@"b]; not valueForKeyPath. After that checking for '== [NSNull null]' is good way.

Comment: __NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxxxx  there is a problem on the json?

Comment: Try to open JSON you have in some editor, then look at the code and see if your code you use same structure. think you treat an array like dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple NSNull workaround, to avoid crashes on NSNull calls

**1) Add this code in your AppDelegate**

```
#import "EXTNil.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

+ (id)swizzled_null
{
    return [EXTNil null];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    SEL originalSelector = @selector(null);
    SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(swizzled_null);

    Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod([NSNull class], originalSelector);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod([self class], swizzledSelector);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    return YES;
}
```

**2) Added (EXTNil and EXTRuntimeExtensions) classes to your project from repo** https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/tree/master/extobjc

Now You can call any method on NSNull